# Prove that $f^3$ and $f$ has the same set of discontinuities

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I have the following question for which I came up with a proof and I want some opinion on the validity of it.

**Question**:

$f$ is bounded real-valued function on $[a,b]$. Show that the set of discontinuities for $f^3$ is the same as that of $f$.

**My attempt**:

Let $D_0 = \{x: f^3 \text{ is discontinuous at }x\}$ and $D_1 = \{x: f \text{ is discontinuous at }x\}$.

**(1)** ($D_0 \subset D_1$) Choose $c \in D_0$, fix $\delta > 0$, choose $x$ and $\epsilon > 0$ s.t. $|x - c| < \delta \implies |f^3(x) - f^3(c)| \geq \epsilon$.

We need to find $\eta > 0$, s.t. $|f(x) - f(c)| \geq \eta$.

Since $f$ is bounded, choose $M > 0$ s.t. $|f(y)| < M, \forall y \in [a,b]$.

Then $|f^3(x) - f^3(c)| \geq \epsilon \implies |f(x) - f(c)||f^2(x) + f(x)f(c) + f^2(c)| \geq \epsilon$, which means $|f(x) - f(c)| \geq \epsilon/|f^2(x) + f(x)f(c) + f^2(c)| > \epsilon/3M^2$.

Since $\delta$ is arbitrary, we then have $\forall \delta > 0$, $\exists \eta = \epsilon/3M^2 > 0$ s.t. $\exists x$ with $|x-c| < \delta$ and yet $|f(x) - f(c)| > \eta$. Therefore, $c$ is a discontinuity of $f$ and $D_0 \subset D_1$.

**(2)** ($D_1 \subset D_0$) Choose $c \in D_1$, fix $\delta > 0$, choose $x$ and $\epsilon > 0$ s.t. $|x - c| < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(c)| \geq \epsilon$.

We need to find $\eta > 0$, s.t. $|f^3(x) - f^3(c)| \geq \eta$.

Notice that $|f(x) - f(c)| \geq \epsilon \implies |f^3(x) - f^3(c)| \geq \epsilon|f^2(x) + f(x)f(c) + f^2(c)|$.

This is true since $f(x)$ and $f(c)$ cannot be identically $0$ since then $|f(x) - f(c)| = 0 < \epsilon$.

Since for any $x, c \in \mathbb{R}$, we have $|f^2(x) + f(x)f(c) + f^2(c)| = (f(x) + f(c)/2)^2 + 3f^2(c)/4 = (f(c) + f(x)/2)^2 + 3f^2(x)/4$, hence, $|f^2(x) + f(x)f(c) + f^2(c)| \geq \max\{3f^2(c)/4, 3f^2(x)/4\}$.

Since at least one of $f(x)$ and $f(c)$ is not equal to $0$, we have $\max\{3f^2(c)/4, 3f^2(x)/4\} = m > 0$ for some $m \in \mathbb{R}$. Hence, $|f^3(x) - f^3(c)| \geq \epsilon m = \eta > 0$.

Since $\delta$ is arbitrary, we then have $\forall \delta > 0$, $\exists \eta > 0$ s.t. $\exists x$ with $|x-c| < \delta$ and yet $|f^3(x) - f^3(c)| > \eta$. Therefore, $c$ is a discontinuity of $f$ and $D_1 \subset D_0$.

Is this proof correct? Thank you very much!

Comment: I would have focused on where the functions are continuous.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown wouldn't that be a very similar argument?

Comment: If there is no requirement that your proof has to be an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof you could do it one line using the fact that $x \to x^{3}$ is a homeomorphism from $\mathbb R$ onto itself (and composition of continuous maps is continuous).

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy That's the thing. I don't think I could use that because it wasn't taught in class.

Comment: Your proof is correct.

Comment: In this question, $f^3(x)$  means $(f(x))^3$ not $f(f(f(x)))$.

Comment: You should state somewhere that the function $f$ is real-valued. If $f$ can be complex-valued the statement is false. Bonus excersice (i), find where your proof fails for complex valued functions, bonus exercise (ii) find a counter example for complex valued functions.

Comment: Yes, it is real valued. I will add that.